# add custom fonts (my website's fonts) in Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, webfonts, wordpress-gutenberg

I'd like to adapt the gutenberg editor to my website's appearance, and use my web-fonts for the various block elements.
I've been looking in the plugin's various folders/CSS-files, but haven't found anything useful.
Where are the font definitions for the editor?

Thank you all!

david

Comment: I am wondering the same things.

Comment: Would be nice if you could accept my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is an official way, but you could create a small plugin (Gutenberg block editor assets without a block, to be precise) for this.

1. Create a folder named `gutenbergfontchanger` (or a better name) inside /wp-content/plugins
2. Add a PHP file named `gutenbergfontchanger.php` with a code similar to this one:

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: gutenbergfontchanger
*/

if (!function_exists('gutenbergfontchanger_editor_assets')) {
    function gutenbergfontchanger_editor_assets()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'gutenbergfontchanger-editor-style',
            plugins_url('editor.css', __FILE__),
            filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'editor.css')
        );
    }

    add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gutenbergfontchanger_editor_assets');
}
```

3. Add a CSS file named `editor.css` containing your font styles:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,600');

.editor-styles-wrapper, .editor-post-title__input {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
}
```

4. Activate the plugin inside your WordPress backend.

Comment: Hello Fabian! This has been a quite long time until this Question finally has found an answer. Thank you! Will check for it, though I don't yet know when. (Have to see if gutenberg works with the theme I'm using...) — best wishes from around the corner!

Comment: No problem :) I'm sure there are other ways to achieve this too, but it worked fine for me.